# Any new functionality to sync smart groups to Drupal roles?

Tags: drupal, roles, civigroup, sync

When last I checked CiviGroup Roles Sync did not work with Smart Groups. Has this changed with later versions (I'm on 5.17).

There were some workarounds discussed back in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine for us.  We are on Civi 5.8 and Drupal 7.x.

Comment: Thanks Richard - that's great news. I'll implement it.